# Adding Local User to Local Admin Group II

Tags: c#, .net, user-accounts

I am writing a C# program to add a local user to a local group (Administrators, for example). I can create a new user, but I am not able to add it to a group. What I have found is if in this group is any domain user or group it is not working. When I try to add it to the group without domain users it is ok. I run this program as a local admin.

```
using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine))
{
    UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(pc, Login, Password, true);
    user.Save();
    GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, "Administrators");
    group.Members.Add(user);
    group.Save();
}
```

When I run it as domain admin it works ok, but I need it only as local admin.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

PS:
I found this:
[Adding Local User to Local Admin Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843469/adding-local-user-to-local-admin-group)
, it is great but it is also not working...

**Update**

I can search for this new user, it exists.

The exception I am getting is

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException. Network path not found

Comment: "*not working*" is not a technical description of a problem. Its like going to the doctor and saying "*I have a hurt*". Do you get any exceptions? Can you search for that user? :)

Comment: Sorry, i am new here. :-) Yes, I can search for this new user, it exists. And exception is: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException. Network path not found.

Comment: Can it be somehow related to ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25060655/c-sharp-principalcontext-the-network-path-was-not-found

Comment: I do not know, I think not. I do it on local machine only (win 10, machine is part of domain), technicaly I do not need domain but the machine is part of it.